# Why is rmarkdown adding NA values to my ggplot when I knit the file?

Tags: r, r-markdown, na

I've been stuck on a particular problem. I've created an rmd file and everything is how I'd like it, however, when I knit the rmd file into any format (HTML, pdf, word) the rmd.file will produce the ggplots with NA values. On the other hand, if I run the code chunks in the rmd script it comes out how it should do with no NA values. Just to note there are no NA values to begin with. Any suggestions for how I could fix this?

images attached below:

[plot 1 before knit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJ0Jc.png)

[plot 1 after knit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE7bN.png)

[plot 2 before knit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsIfK.png)

[plot 2 after knit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1ax5.png)

Comment: `mean(ride_length, na.rm = T)`

Comment: I assume that your data in your working environment already is without the NA's and hence when you run the chunks manually everything works fine.

Comment: @Julian Sadly it didn't work. And yes that's correct, there aren't any NA values to begin with which is why I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Try `rm(list = ls())` and run every chunk manually and see whether the NA's appear (without the fix of @elidomx of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't try it myself without some reproducible example, but have you tried including `drop_na()` function?

```
all_trips_v2 %>% 
  drop_na() %>% ...
```

or maybe below

```
... arrange(user_type, weekday) %>% 
drop_na() %>% ...
```

Comment: ```... arrange(user_type, weekday) %>% 
drop_na() %>% ...``` Thank you! It worked thankfully, but it's also a question as to why it's adding NA values when there are none to begin with?

Comment: My best guess is that there actually were some NA values in your dataframe, and that ggplot removes them automatically when called directly from the script, but not when knitting the html/pdf. There are some inconsistencies like that when knitting :(